# jQuery Drag and Drop Checking Question

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

i am new to using jQuery and I just want to know how I can check whether a draggable object has been removed from the droppable object.

Example, i have a dog and I dragged it to a doghouse which has a lightbulb that will light up indicating that the dog is there. When i drag the dog out of the doghouse, the lightbulb should go off again indicating the dog's absence.

Help me please coz I really don't have any idea how to do this. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the the [drop event][1] embedded in UI / draggable. Here's some example code:

```
$("#doghouse").droppable(
    {drop:function(event,ui){
        if (ui.draggable[0].id=="dog"){
            //show lightbulb
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the immediate response. i'm sorry but i didn't quite get that. i'm really new to using jQuery like 1 day old. Can you point me to some examples or just a short code  so that i'll have something to ponder on? Thanks a lot.

Comment: now i get what you were saying but, with all due respect, i don't think this is exactly what i needed. this only covers up the dragging part. but what i wanted to do is to check if a draggable item (dog) has been removed from a droppable item (doghouse) which will make the light go out. not just the dragging part. thanks for helping me out.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable#event-out i think this is what i needed but i don't quite know how to use this. :(

Comment: You are right, the drop event works even better. See my edit above.

Comment: Ive also added an example to get you started.